# How to use quotes in a macro on Windows

Tags: c++, ant

I'm trying to compile this piece of code:

```
std::string myString(...)
if (myString == __MY_MACRO__) { ... }
```

In my ant script, I have:

```
<property unless:set="myprop" name="myprop" value="foo" />
...
<compilerarg value='-D__MY_MACRO__="${myprop}"' />
```

It compiles on Linux but not on Windows where I get the following error:

```
[cc] <command-line>:0:27: error: 'foo' was not declared in this scope
[cc] XXX.cpp:X:Y: note: in expansion of macro '__MY_MACRO__'
[cc]          if (myString == __MY_MACRO__) {
```

I also tried with

```
<compilerarg value="-D__MY_MACRO__=&quot;${myprop}&quot;" />
```

But had the same result.

Thanks !

Comment: Don't use macros whenever there a other options.

Comment: Does it work if you hard code like this `<compilerarg value='-D__MY_MACRO__="foo"' />`?

Comment: This question is more about how Java (Ant) is invoking the shell (cmd?) and what the shell does with the quotes. In any case it is not an easy feat to get quotes, backslashes, dollar signs and such passed through the shell in a portable way.

Comment: @manni66 what are the other options ?

Comment: @MichaelWalz hard coding foo doesn't work either. So it means the issue comes when calling the compiler and not before that.

Comment: Try to compile the .c file "manually" by invoking `gcc -c -D__MY_MACRO__=foo` and `gcc -c -D__MY_MACRO__="foo"`. I supose the first version will compile but not the second. RustyX's comment sounds reasonable.

Comment: Ant properties are immutable, so your `unless:set` attribute on the same property you're setting is redundant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution :

```
<compilerarg value='-D__MY_MACRO__="\"${myprop}"\"' />
```